# How to implement feedback dialog in bot service?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I am developing a bot service using botframework with c#.

I want to show a feedback dialog to the user at the end of dialog.
And I want to save the feedback contents to the external cloud storage.

I want to embed it in this source, but I have no idea how to implement it.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/70.qnamaker-multiturn-sample

There were some sample of node.js, but I couldn't find sample of qna maker + C #
Can anyone tell me a sample source that I think would be helpful?

Comment: Can you clarify; when you say 'feedback' are you talking about a dialog/prompt that will allow the user to give feedback or a rating? Or are you talking about QnAMaker [active learning training](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base#train-api)?

Comment: I'm talking about a dialog/prompt that will allow the user to give feedback or a rating.

Comment: I am glad to inform you that the problem is now solved.

I added the following two steps in QnAMakeMultiturnDialog.cs
step1:display feedback prompt
step2:correct response of feedback

And I sent the feedback response to Applications Insights.